# jQuery, use ~ as a part of id - how?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In my application I have a form, which elements are named using a certain convention, i.e. they are paths, the parts of which are separated using the `~` sign.

Now I need to access one of them in jQuery by id, but I fail. Apparently, jQuery treats it as the `#prev ~ sibling` thing.

Is there a way I can sort of escape the `~` sign in the jQuery function?

Here is an example of what my code looks like:

```
<select id="a~b~c">
  <option value='1'>one</opiton>
</select>

<script>
  $("#a~b~c").change(function(){
    alert('a');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
  $("#a\\~b\\~c").change(function(){
    alert('a');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\\` http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('#a\\~b\\~c')
```

Or, if escaping is problematic you can use: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

```
$('[id="a~b~c"]')
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qv6pa/1/)

Comment: Either that or double backslash (\\\) as it turned out.

Comment: @ibolit True, I added that with a link to an article on it.

Comment: By the way, the $('[id]="..."') variant didn't work for me... :(

Comment: @Ibolit, it's actually `[id="a~b~c"]` not `[id]="a~b~c"`

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer to that in the [official jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F).

You need to escape it with `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

The escape character in jQuery is two backslahses, `\\`, so try this:

```
$("#a\\~b\\~c").change(function(){    
    alert('a');
});
```

[**Fiddle to show it working**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Gu8GF/)

Further reading on jQuery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/