# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #categories_id(categories)

Tags: jquery, node.js

i am using id with brackets in jquery but it's giving error

```
$("#categories_id(categories)").val("hello");
```

Result

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #categories_id(categories)

Comment: Don't put brackets in ID values?

Comment: but i have to give with id

Comment: what is exactly html id="" tag of your object?

Comment: Use element selector or escape the brackets as in the answer below

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery, use ~ as a part of id - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226331/jquery-use-as-a-part-of-id-how)

Comment: Pretty sure there are 100s of possible duplicates, above is just first one

Answer (score 1):

You can use element selector for that as `$("[id='categories_id(categories)']")`:

```js
$("[id='categories_id(categories)']").val("hello");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='categories_id(categories)' />
```

Or you can even escape the round brackets using `$('#categories_id\\(categories\\)')`:

```js
$('#categories_id\\(categories\\)').val("hello");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='categories_id(categories)' />
```